# Getting files permanently saved

Tags: linux

I need your help.

I'm wracking my brain in order to understand how tmpfs works.

I have a thin client machine whose o.s is Suse Linux.

If I get access to the system through admin user and create a file in `/home/admin/Desktop` after reboot the file is still
there.

But if I create a file in `/usr/lib/cups/filter` after reboot the file is gone.
Of course you would say if the file system is tmpfs nothing might sound strange.
Right, but why does the file created in `/home/admin/Desktop` gets preserved after restart?

mount command shows:

```
tmpfs on / type tmpfs (rw)

proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)

devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)

tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,mode=1777)

devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,mode=0620,gid=5)

usb on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw)
```

Is there a way to get files permanently saved in `/usr/lib/cups/filter` after reboot?

How do things work?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your machine does not have a disk! Because of this, you cannot save *anything* to it permanently.

You can only save to `/home` because it is a remote filesystem exported from another computer.

Comment: The list of mount points in the question does not include `/home`, which means something does not quite add up. It is however likely that some information is missing in the question, and your guess turns out to be entirely correct anyhow.

Comment: @kasperd I guess that it's either automounted, or the OP intentionally omitted it.